# Expect script - sometimes no log generated

Tags: linux, expect

I have a simple expect script that supplies password 4 times.
I am logging the output to a log file using

log_file -a /home/applusr/e291505/logs/ADD.log
spawn /home/root/admin/add.mims.user $username "$firstname $lastname"

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect
set username [lindex $argv 0]
set firstname [lindex $argv 1]
set lastname [lindex $argv 2]
set mypassword [lindex $argv 3]
set userpassword [lindex $argv 4]
set LOG_FILE [open /home/applusr/e291505/logs/ADD.log a]
set today [ exec /bin/date +%Y-%m-%d-%T]
puts $LOG_FILE "\n------------------ADD_SCRIPT - $today----$username--$firstname--$lastname---"
set timeout 10
log_user 1
log_file -a /home/applusr/e291505/logs/ADD.log
spawn /home/root/admin/add.mims.user $username "$firstname $lastname"
expect  "e291505's Password:*" { send "$mypassword\n" }
expect  "$username's New password:*" { send "$userpassword\n" }
expect  "Enter the new password again:*" { send "$userpassword\n" }
expect  "Password:*" { send "$mypassword\n" }
```

If I run the script:

Sometimes the output is in the log file. No issues.
Sometimes, there is no put in the log file except the puts statement output.

puts $LOG_FILE "\n------------------ADD_SCRIPT - $today----$username--$firstname--$lastname---"

How do I guarantee that log file will always have output?

Comment: Try `close $LOG_FILE` before `log_file`

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman  Added close $LOG_FILE. Now the password prompts are logged everytime but the output of the script AFTER the prompts is not logged. i.e after the 4 passwords are supplied it says user added successfully etc that part is not logged.

Comment: I observed that the log file has the actual password supplied for the 4th time i.e------------------ADD_SCRIPT - 2020-02-20-14:18:20----b000080--User1--test1---
Changing password for "b000080"
e233305's Password:
u000050's New password:
Enter the new password again:
Password:**Nhy^7ujm**     I added debug_log as well and last thing the expect debug_log has in the password supplied for the 4th time.

Answer (score 1):

(edited for completeness to include comment by glenn jackman, and later ones by me).

1. You need to `close $LOG_FILE` before using `log_file` or you have 2 independent file descriptors to the same file, and it seems to be indeterminate in which order the writes will be done.
2. To get all output logged:
   `expect` will only copy input it has read to the log. Your last line gets `expect` to read and look for the password prompt. Then your program stops. You need to add something more to get it to read any further output, so that it can be logged too. Typically, you wait for the spawned command to finish and close the file descriptor by adding

   ```
   expect eof
   ```
3. The log shows only what is received, so normally sent passwords are not seen as echo will be turned off at that point. If you do see the 4th password then you may need to add a small delay after matching the prompt to let the remote switch echo off. eg:

   ```
   { sleep 1; send "$mypassword\n" }
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt help. I added debug info by adding line

exp_internal -f debug_info.log 0;


After sending the 4th password, the program again sees/encounters the password itself

send: sending "Xsw@3edc\n" to { exp8 }^M
Xsw@3edc^M
expect: timed out^M

Comment: I was assuming the spawned program `add.mims.user` was going to finish after you had sent the 4th password. Perhaps it takes longer than 10 seconds to finish its work and end?

Comment: After the 4th password is supplied, it does some oracle commands but that finishes within 2-3 seconds when I run the program manually. In the expect program the 4th password gets printed out in the logs, none of the 3 above get printed. That was odd.

Comment: The log shows only what is received, so normally sent passwords are not seen as echo will be turned off at that point. If you see the 4th password you may need to add a small delay after matching the prompt to let the remote switch echo off.  eg: `{ sleep 1; send "$mypassword\n" }`

Comment: Thanks. Adding sleep did help with the password logged in log file. thanks